# which button should be shown

Tags: python, tkinter

Suppose we have a lot of buttons with specified texts & locations.

For example our buttons are {'main','report', 'memory', 'bills',...},
now we have an array that determine which button should be visible.

For example z1=['report', 'bills'], the contents of this array can be the other buttons. In your oponions, how can i write the code? Should i compare the text of every button with "z1" array, before defining every button? This is not reasonable, because the numbers of buttons are a lot.

This is my sample code:

```
    z1=['report','bills','setting']

    self.button = Button(self.master,text="memory", command=self.ouvrir)
    self.button.grid(row=1, column=1)

    self.button2 = Button(self.master,text="report", command=self.tabluh)
    self.button2.grid(row=1, column=2)


    self.button3 = Button(self.master,text="setting", command=self.new_window)
    self.button3.grid(row=1, column=3)

    self.button4 = Button(self.master,text="calibration", command=self.cal)
    self.button4.grid(row=1, column=4)


    self.button5 = Button(self.master,text="empty weight", command=self.weighing)
    self.button5.grid(row=1, column=5)

    self.button6 = Button(self.master,text="bills", command=self.history)
    self.button6.grid(row=1, column=6) 

    self.button7 = Button(self.master,text="full weight", command=self.full)
    self.button7.grid(row=1, column=7)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by storing your commands in a dictionary as values and the text as the keys. If you give the GUI a list containing the keys you want to see, he will select the right keys from this. Next, you dynamically create the buttons.

Kind regards, S

```
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self, root,a):
        self.root = root
        action = self.find_command(a)

        for y,element in enumerate(action):
            self.Make_Button(1,y, element[0], element[1])



    def find_command(self, list_):
        d = {"test": self.printX, "value" : self.printY, "practice" : self.printZ}
        action = []
        for element in list_:
            for key, value in d.items():
                if key == element:
                    action.append([key, value])
        return(action)


    def Make_Button(self, x, y, text_, command_):
        self.StopButton = Button(self.root, text = text_, command =  command_)
        self.StopButton.grid(row = x, column = y, columnspan = 1, pady=(2,1))

    def printX(self):
        print("testX")

    def printY(self):
        print("testY")

    def printZ(self):
        print("testZ")


a = ["test", "practice"]

root = Tk()
Window = Window(root,a)
Window.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of overwriting self.StopButton, I suggest you use `setattr(self, button_'+text.replace(" ","_"), button]` . This also stores the button by name, so you can acces it later (using `getattr`), if you'd like to perform an action on it.

Comment: thank you ...it's very good...how can i detemine a fixed location for every button(either being button or not being it)???

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. The location on the grid? This you do by changing the x and y coordinates